# Unable to load my URL in Android WebView but URL loading in Android Browser

Tags: android, android-webview

I m trying to load one of my cloud URL from android webview but it returns HTTP Status 401 always. If i tried from Chrome mobile browser its working as expected. Even in iOS WebView its working fine.

Here is my code, Please someone help me.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xoi);

    base_url = "https://vision.xoeye.io/partners/abcd/share?";
String params = "shareId=12345678910111213141516" +
        "&serviceTicket=123-123&" +
        "customer=Manikanta&" +
        "location=3201 S. State St. Chicago IL 60616";

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.clearFormData();
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });


    webView.loadUrl(base_url);
}
```

Comment: @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your base url try logging it and run time copy that logged url and paste in browser

Comment: I took url while debugging app and i pasted in browser.@Mr. Patil

Comment: I added my url in the code snippet. Please someone check once

Answer (score 1):

> Try This

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_xoi);

     base_url = base_url+params;
     webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

     WebSettings webSettings=webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        //add here additional setting which you want
        webView.loadUrl(base_url);
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Mohsin Kazi, Nothing changes in result.

Comment: //override this method                                                                                    
     @Override
    public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,
            HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        handler.proceed("Your User Name", "Your Password");
    }        //add this code in HelloWebViewClient class  -  Manikanta Ottiprolu